# Inequality regarding quotients of $\operatorname{arcsinh}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Doing something with differential geometry, the following question popped up:

> Given $L>0$, does there exist $M>0$ such that $$\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}(\lambda x)}{\operatorname{arcsinh}(\lambda y)}\leq M$$ for all $0<\lambda<1$ and all $x,y>0$ such that $\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}( x)}{\operatorname{arcsinh}( y)}\leq L ?$

If $x<y$, the bound $M=1$ suffices, however I don't know what happens for the other cases.

Comment: The question can be reformulated as "does $f(x)\le f(y)^L$ imply $f(\lambda x)\le f(\lambda y)^M$ for all $0<\lambda<1$ where $$f(x)=x+\sqrt{1+x^2}$$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{arcsinh}(x) = \ln (x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1})$.

If $L > 1$, there does not exist such $M$ based on the following facts:

1) If $L > 1$, let $x_0 = \frac{(1+y)^L - 1}{2}$. We have
$$\frac{\ln (x_0 + \sqrt{x_0^2 + 1})}{\ln (y + \sqrt{y^2 + 1})}
\le \frac{\ln (2x_0 + 1)}{\ln (y + 1)} = L.$$

2) If $L > 1$, by using L'Hospital's rule, we have $\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{x_0}{y} = \lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{(1+y)^L - 1}{2y} = \infty$.

3) By using L'Hospital's rule, we have
$$\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \frac{\ln (\lambda x + \sqrt{(\lambda x)^2 + 1})}{\ln (\lambda y + \sqrt{(\lambda y)^2 + 1})} = \frac{x}{y}.$$